# Correct way to include a sidebar across many templates?

Tags: flask, wtforms

I'm trying to figure out the best way to include some sidebar code that will be used on almost every one of my templates. For example, my `index.html` is

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
    Hello, ...
    {% include 'sidebar.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

The view is:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    # some stuff for my index page...
    form_sidebar = sidebar()
    return render_template('index.html', indexdata=indexdata, form_sidebar=form_sidebar)
```

My sidebar form is created with

```
def sidebar():
    form_sidebar = MySideBarForm()  # defined in forms.py
    # do some sql stuff to initialize the form ...
    return form_sidebar
```

My `sidebar.html` uses the data received from `sidebar()`.

If I continue in this manner then every one of my view functions will have to call `sidebar()`, they will all have to pass along the varialbe `form_sidebar`, and every template will need to `{% include 'sidebar.html' %}`. Is there a better way to do this? I think ideally my `base.html` would `{% include 'sidebar.html`, but then I don't know how to provide it with the `form_sidebar` data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could include your `form_sidebar` in the global `g` which is implicitly available in templates if I am not mistaken.

To feed `g` you can do it globally in a `@before_request` decorated function and including the sidebar template in the base template should finish the job.